# trying tio connect to phoenix table with pyspark and getting the following error

Tags: hadoop, apache-phoenix

my commnd for reading phoenix table:
sql_sc.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", tablename).option("zkUrl", "10.0.11.21:2181").load()
error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bdaas/exe/healthcare/hl7visualization.py", line 42, in 
    hl7 = phoenix_sparkdata(spark_app='hl7-app',spark_master='local',table_name='hl7table_v2_3')
  File "/bdaas/exe/healthcare/hl7visualization.py", line 19, in **init**
    self.dataframe = self.phoenix_getdataframe(table_name)
  File "/bdaas/exe/healthcare/hl7visualization.py", line 41, in phoenix_getdataframe
    df = self.sql_sc.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", tablename).option("zkUrl", "10.0.11.21:2181").load()
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 139, in load
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in **call**
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:49)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.ScalaNumberDeserializersModule$class.$init$(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:61)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.(DefaultScalaModule.scala:35)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.(RDDOperationScope.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(SparkContext.scala:1152)
        at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.(PhoenixRDD.scala:46)
        at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRelation.schema(PhoenixRelation.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: check to see if you have the right dependency jar files installed.  it seems you are missing fasterxml jackson

Comment: thanks for responding, I have added the jars in spark defaults conf as per the phoenix documentation. But I could not find anything about this fasterxmljackson .